# Finding dynamically created elements by class using document.querySelectorAll() fails in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

### Some Context

I have a web page that uses the a service to provide a menu of items. It works by adding your info to the database on the provider's site, and placing their JavaScript on your page that grabs the data and adds the elements dynamically to your page.

Since the menu is long, I wanted to create an index at the top of the page that uses just the titles of each menu item, so visitors can see each type of item that's available at a glance. Also, since I won't be the one updating the database, I wanted the menu to create itself from the content generated by the other service.

The dynamically created content from the service uses a particular class for each menu item header. I wrote a script that gets each element with this class and creates an index with the content. Success! Sort of...

### Here's the Problem

My script works in all current browsers except IE9 and below (although I'm not too worried about below IE 9). I've narrowed the problem down to `document.querySelectorAll()`, which is returning an empty node list in IE 9. I've read about issues with trying to access dynamically created DOM elements using `querySelectorAll()`, but can't seem to find a solution.

Interestingly, `querySelectorAll` returns a zero-length node list when the script runs on window load, but when I type the same code directly into the IE developer console (F12), running in IE 9 document mode, the script returns the complete node list.

### Update

Link to the [service provider's library](http://menus.singleplatform.co/businesses/storefront).

The code that calls the library is inserted into the page as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://menus.singleplatform.co/businesses/storefront/API KEY OMITTED">
</script>
<script>
    var options = {};
    options['PrimaryBackgroundColor'] = '#FFFFE1';
    options['MenuDescBackgroundColor'] = '#d9d9d9';
    options['SectionTitleBackgroundColor'] = '#FFFFE1';
    options['SectionDescBackgroundColor'] = '#f1f1f1';
    options['FeedbackSubmitBackgroundColor'] = '#f1f1f1';
    options['ItemBackgroundColor'] = '#ffffff';
    options['FeedbackBackgroundColor'] = '#ffffff';
    options['FeedbackCancelBackgroundColor'] = '#ffffff';
    options['PrimaryFontFamily'] = 'Roboto';
    options['BaseFontSize'] = '15px';
    options['FontCasing'] = 'Default';
    options['PrimaryFontColor'] = '#573A2C';
    options['MenuDescFontColor'] = '#000000';
    options['SectionTitleFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['SectionDescFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['FeedbackSubmitFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['ItemTitleFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['FeedbackFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['FeedbackFieldFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['FeedbackCancelFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['ItemDescFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['ItemPriceFontColor'] = '#555555';
    options['MenuTemplate'] = '2';
    new BusinessView("business-identifier", "target-element-id", options);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure querySelectorAll is running after the nodes are inserted into the DOM?

Comment: Do you realize that the target elements must exist BEFORE you run `querySelectorAll()`?  So, if you run `querySelectorAll()` and THEN you insert the target elements, the elements were not present when `querySelectorAll()` was run, thus the elements are not returned.  It is possible that browser differences are due to timing differences in when the content is loaded or how it is cached.

Comment: @bfavaretto Is there a way to ensure my script runs after all other content is loaded?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm aware the elements I need have to exist before I try to access them, I'm just not sure how to guarantee that they exist before my script runs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Youl'd have to explain how the elements are being created/loaded before we could know how to wait for that.  If it's done via an ajax call, then you need to do the `querySelectorAll()` operation AFTER the from the ajax call completion handler after the content has been inserted.

Comment: As jfriend00 said, you have to show us the "placing their JavaScript on your page" part.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question to include a link to the service provider's library and the code used in the page to call it.

Comment: @bfavaretto Please see updates above.